# Django Model Choices: IntegerField vs CharField

Tags: sql-server, django, indexing, django-models

**TL;DR**: I have a table with millions of instances and I'm wondering how should I index it.

I have a Django project that uses SQL Server as the database backend.

After having a model with around 14 million instances in the Production environment, I realized that I was getting performance issues:

```
class UserEvent(models.Model)

    A_EVENT = 'A'
    B_EVENT = 'B'

    types = (
        (A_EVENT, 'Event A'),
        (B_EVENT, 'Event B')
    )

    event_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=types)

    contract = models.ForeignKey(Contract)

    # field_x = (...)
    # field_y = (...)
```

I use a lot of queries based in this field, and it is being highly inefficient, since the field isn't indexed. Filtering the model using only by this field takes almost 7 seconds, while querying by an indexed foreign key doesn't carry performance issues:

```
UserEvent.objects.filter(event_type=UserEvent.B_EVENT).count()
# elapsed time: 0:00:06.921287

UserEvent.objects.filter(contract_id=62).count()
# elapsed time: 0:00:00.344261
```

When I realized this, I also made a question to myself: "Shouldn't this field be a SmallIntegerField? Since I only have a small set of choices, and queries based in integer fields are more efficient than text/varchar based queries."

So, from what I understand, I have two options*:

> *I realize that a third option may exist, since [indexing fields with low cardinality may not cause severe improvements](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/101096), but since my values have a [1%-99%] distribution (and I'm looking for the 1% part), indexing this field seems to be a valid option.

- **A)** Simply index this field, and leave it as a CharField.

  ```
  A_EVENT = 'A'
  B_EVENT = 'B'

  types = (
      (A_EVENT, 'Event A'),
      (B_EVENT, 'Event B')
  )

  event_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=types, db_index=True)
  ```
- **B)** Perform a migration to transform this field in a SmallIntegerField (I don't want it to be a BooleanField, since it may be possible to add more options to the field), and then index the field.

  ```
  A_EVENT = 1
  B_EVENT = 2

  types = (
      (A_EVENT, 'Event A'),
      (B_EVENT, 'Event B')
  )

  event_type = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=types, db_index=True)
  ```

#### Option A

**Pros:** Simplicity

**Cons:** [CharField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#charfield) based indexes are less efficient than Integer based indexes

#### Option B

**Pros:** Integer based indexes are more efficient than [CharField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#charfield) based indexes

**Cons:** I have to perform a complex operation:

1. Schema migration to create a new  [SmallIntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#smallintegerfield)
2. Data migration copying (and transforming) the millions of instances from the old field to the new field.
3. Update the project code to use the new field or perform another schema migration to rename the new field as the previous one.
4. Delete the old field.

---

Summing up, the real question here is:

**The performance improvement I get from migrating the field to a SmallIntegerField worths the risk?**

I'm leaned to try option A, and check if the performance improvements are adequate.

---

I also brought up this question to StackOverflow because a more generic question arised:

- Is there any situation where using CharFields along the Django choices is a better option than using Boolean/Integer/SmallIntegerField?

This situation was originated because when defining the project models I was inspired by [Django documentation code snippet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#choices):

```
YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = (
     ('FR', 'Freshman'),
     ('SO', 'Sophomore'),
     ('JR', 'Junior'),
     ('SR', 'Senior'),
)

year_in_school = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                  choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,
                                  default=FRESHMAN)
```

**Why are they using chars when they could be using integers, since it is just a value representation that shouldn't never be displayed?**

Comment: The actual query that you are having performance issues will be a usefull addition.

Comment: @e4c5 I've added query examples to the question :)

Comment: I would say that they are using characters because of readability. You still may use the value representation in extra logic.
If you have a test server/db I would recommend just trying it out and see if there are any benefits to migrating production over.
I don't think there will be much difference in terms of storage space used.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

**Speed of Count queries.**

```
UserEvent.objects.filter(event_type=UserEvent.B_EVENT).count()
# elapsed time: 0:00:06.921287
```

Queries of this nature, unfortunately will always be slow in databases when the table has a large number of entries.

Mysql optimizes count queries by looking at the index [provided the indexed columns are numeric](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/where-optimizations.html). So that's a good reason to use SmallIntegeField instead of Charfield if you were on mysql but apparently you are not. Your mileage varies with other databases. I am not an expert on SQL server but my understanding is that it's [particularly poor at using indexes](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/sql-server/why-is-my-select-count-running-so-slow/) on COUNT(*) queries.

**Partitioning**

You might be able to improve overall performance of queries involving event_type by partitioning the data. Because the cardinality of the current index is poor it's often better for the planner to do a full table scan. If the data was partitioned, only that particular partition would need to be scanned.

**Char or Smallint**

Which takes up more space char(2) or small int? The answer is that it depends on your character set. If the character set requires only one byte per character small integer and char(2) would take up the same amount of space. Since the field is going to have very low cardinality, using char or smallint will not make any significant difference in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your input.

Actually, I used the count query to prove an example. The most common case is to filter by event_type along a boolean field to get a list of instances.

Comment: you have lead yourself and us on a wild goose chase! Can't judge performance from a count query.

Comment: Thanks for your input.

Actually, I used the count query to prove an example. The most common case is to filter by event_type along a boolean field to get a list of instances.

I was given the idea that the index performance isn't related to the storage space, but with the datatype. Even if a Small Int takes up more space, isn't more efficient than a Char?

Meanwhile, since 99% of the data was not being used by the application, and we were able to store it outside this database, we decided to stop storing all info, and just store the data required by the application.

Comment: Ok, you are right, it was a misleading example. I apologize about that.

But the performance issue is real. And I think the question about index performance and impact is worth it.