# Any reason to use integers over strings in choices?

Tags: django, database, performance, django-models

Consider the following:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
  PRIORITY_LOW = 0
  PRIORITY_NORMAL = 1
  PRIORITY_HIGH = 2
  PRIORITIES = (
    (PRIORITY_LOW, 'Low'),
    (PRIORITY_NORMAL, 'Normal'),
    (PRIORITY_HIGH, 'High'),
  )

  priority = models.IntegerField(default=0, choices=PRIORITIES)
```

Is there any reason not to do the following, instead?

```
class Thing(models.Model):      
  PRIORITIES = (
    ('low', 'Low'),
    ('normal', 'Normal'),
    ('high', 'High'),
  )

  priority = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="low", choices=PRIORITIES)
```

Benefits: less code, and now I can simply type `"normal"` instead of `models.Thing.PRIORITY_NORMAL`.

Are there any downsides, perhaps from a database perspective?

Comment: not a dup but some of the points are discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36716147/267540